# Loop in List of Map in get Query JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, list, dictionary, jdbc

I'm trying to make a get result of my query with List<Map<String, String>> result

But I'm blocked because I don't see how I can do the loop in my List Map and I have an error in method put

This is a part of  my method  with the loop for below :

```
protected List<Map<String, String>> getAllResultForQuery(String sql) throws SQLException {
    List<Map<String, String>> result = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {

        // Create connection
        conn = endpoint.getDBConnection();

        // Execute a query
        stmt = conn.createStatement();

        // Let us select all the records and display them.
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        LOG.debug("Execute query: " + sql);

        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        int nbColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
        //loop
        for (Map<String, String> map : result) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                if (rs.next()) {
                    if (result == null) {
                        result = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    }
                    for (int i = 1; i <= nbColumns; i++) {
                        String columnName = rsmd.getColumnName(i).toUpperCase();
                        String columnValue = rs.getString(i);
                        result.put(columnName, columnValue);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Anyone can Help please ?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot add stuff to a map or list while iterating through it

Comment: Or at least according to the documentation the behavior is undefined and might depend on the implementation of such a list or map

Comment: Also you are trying to iterate a list which is null at the time of starting your for loop:
for (Map<String, String> map : result) {

Comment: result was not defined before. Are you trying to iterate your ResultSet?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
protected List<Map<String, String>> getAllResultForQuery(String sql) throws SQLException {
    List<Map<String, String>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    try (Connection conn = endpoint.getDBConnection();
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql)) {
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        int nbColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= nbColumns; i++) {
                String columnName = rsmd.getColumnName(i).toUpperCase();
                String columnValue = rs.getString(i);
                map.put(columnName, columnValue);
            }
            result.add(map);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Yup your answer is better than mine (the one I deleted). Well done

Answer (score 0):

I make like this :

```
   for (Map result : results) {

                if (rs.next()) {
                    if (result == null) {
                        result = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    }
                    for (int i = 1; i <= nbColumns; i++) {
                        String columnName = rsmd.getColumnName(i).toUpperCase();
                        String columnValue = rs.getString(i);
                        result.put(columnName, columnValue);
                    }
                }
            }
```

How do you think ?